# Angular ng serve is not hosting site on localhost

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-cli

When I run `ng serve` on my CLI, I get the following output:

> Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/

But when I open http://localhost:4200/ in my browser so there is nothing.

Any advice on how to solve this issue?

Here's my `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "eastlaw",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors on your console?

Comment: it's not opening on browser so how can I check my console?

Comment: @Shankar web page is not open on my brower when I try to open so page says "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: try with IP address once i.e. `http://127.0.0.1:4200` and did you tried with `ng serve -o`

Comment: @skdroid yes I tried but still not working

Comment: Okay, there are no errors in the console only you are getting "this site can't be reached" that means the "connection is refused" so you could use `--host` flag with your pc IPv4 address (just for testing).

Comment: it also show same error "Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/"

Comment: no I mean to say use host flag to serve, check the answer I've explained steps

Answer (score 3):

To debug the issue try the following :

- ng serve -o
- Check the default port mentioned in config file with the key **baseURL**
- check with ng build command (if webpack is getting generated)
- ng serve --port 8080 --host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck true

if possible try to upload browser console image

Comment: not working same issue.. the page says "This site can’t be reached"

Answer (score 2):

Consider these things :

1. By opening server via `ng serve`, it can only be opened on
   browsers on that device.
2. If you want to serve it for the devices on your network you should use `ng serve -- 
   host <your_device_ip>`

> Note: Device IP is the IP Address of the device you are serving from.

Comment: @WebMaster also  make sure  you have specified the `bootstrap component`  in `root module` and also `root module` to start up in `main.ts`

Comment: Windows firewall may also be an issue, Windows firewall does prompt to you whether or not allow NodeJS access to network. Make sure you allowed access.

Comment: The bootstrap component must not cause any connectivity issue

Comment: I know , but since he said  nothing is seen on the screen . perhaps he has not pointed to angular any component to load . Since there  is no error in console

Answer (score 1):

First, verify your machine IP Address.

On Windows, type `ipconfig` in Prompt (copy IPv4). On Mac, type i`fconfig |grep inet` in Terminal (copy inet).

In my case, this is 192.168.0.10. Next, type the command `ng serve --host 192.168.0.10` Ok, your app on air for all devices on the same network.

Now only `http://192.168.0.10:4200/` will work, localhost not more.

Comment: are you getting any error in terminal/CMD while executing ng serve, could you add your CLI output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 kinds of solutions:

- Step 1 - Typing `ng serve --port 4300` when the project is started
- Step 2 - The region that needs to be changed in the `angular.json` file is below.

  ```
   "serve": {
       "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
       "options": {
         "browserTarget": "productName:build",
         "port": 4300
       }
  ```